# Mock Azure Function HttpTrigger and Setup Query String

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, moq, xunit

I am working on xUnit for.NET CORE Azure Function that have `HttpTrigger`. I have managed to mock HttpTrigger that expect to receive data in the body but struggling with Query String. I have made the generic function outside the test class so that it can be used by other Azure Functions tests.

I need help to create mock for HttpRequest that accept query string. I believe need mock that Setup type of `IQueryCollection`

#### Azure function

```
[FunctionName("MyFunction")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "DELETE")] HttpRequest req,
  [ServiceBus("MyServiceBus", Connection = "MyServiceBusConn")] IAsyncCollector<Message> servicebusMessage)
{
    string sessionId = string.Empty;
    var DateTimeNow = DateTime.Now;
    sessionId = req.Query["sessions"]; //Mock to return this??
}
```

#### Method To Create Mock for HttpRequest Body

```
public Mock<HttpRequest> CreateMockRequest(object body)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

    writer.Write(json);
    writer.Flush();

    memoryStream.Position = 0;

    var mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequest>();

    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.Body).Returns(memoryStream);
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.ContentType).Returns("application/json");

    return mockRequest;
}
```

Need help in following method

#### Method To Create Mock for HttpRequest Query String

```
public Mock<HttpRequest> CreateQueryMockRequest(object body)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var writer = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

    var mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.Query).Returns(json); // This doesn't work??
    mockRequest.Setup(x => x.ContentType).Returns("application/json");

    return mockRequest;
}
```

#### Test Class

```
[Fact]
public void Function_ShouldReturn_XYZ()
{
    //Arrange
    var providerSessionId = RingGoExemptionTestData.GetProviderSession(); //GetProviderSession() implementation below

    Mock<HttpRequest> mockHttpRequest = httpResquestFactory.CreateQueryMockRequest(providerSessionId); // this is where I am trying to use method define above
}
```

#### Dto Object for Query String

```
public static RingGoSession GetProviderSession()
{
    var ringGoSession = new RingGoSession
    {
        RingGoRef = "232d3f"
    };

    return ringGoSession;
}
```

Comment: Consider using a `DefaultHttoContext` and populated the required members as needed. Will save you have to mock up all those members. Only set the ones you need to use.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have put answer below;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

got the answer;

'Generic Method to deal with Query String`

```
 public Mock<HttpRequest> CreateMockHttpRequest(Dictionary<string, StringValues> query)
 {
        var context = new DefaultHttpContext();

        var request = context.Request;

        request.Query = new QueryCollection(query);

        var mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequest>();

        mockRequest.Setup(x => x.Query).Returns(request.Query);

        return mockRequest;
    }
```

`This is how to create Mock by passing Query`

```
  var query = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();
  query.TryAdd("myKey", MyKeyValue);

  Mock<HttpRequest> mockHttpRequest = httpResquestFactory.CreateMockHttpRequest(query);
```

Comment: What you have will work but you could have actually just used the request from the context

Comment: If I try and create a QueryCollection I get 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.QueryCollection' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=3.1.31.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. Why does it allow you?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new instance of `QueryCollection` (read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.querycollection?view=aspnetcore-6.0)) and setup the mock.

```
var mockDict = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>
{
        { "key1", "some value" },
        { "sessions", "random session string"}
};

mockRequest.Setup(x => x.Query).Returns(new QueryCollection(mockDict));
```